# Can't unmerge cells

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I have a lot of data in a Google spreadsheet that depends on charts I spent ages trying to make look pretty.

There is a stupid block of merged cells that won't unmerge, and when I try to cut-and-paste the main block of data, it doesn't paste where it should (presumably because of the stupid merged cells).

So I can't unmerge, and I can't cut-and-paste, and I definitely can't be bothered to spend all that time again to make a new spreadsheet.

What do I do? Why can't I unmerge? I can't even highlight it red in the snapshot below. When I do, it highlights a completely different row (the orangey one starting with the word #motifs).

[image]

Comment: Good idea, the data's quite confidential.. but i'll see if i can replicate what i've done to a smaller scale and send the link

Comment: @pnuts your hunch is very true...

Comment: I'll try a lil later, sorry, so many things I need to do today!